# I installed sql server 2008 r2 on vista 32, but can't find sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I first installed visual studio 2010 express edition, and I think it installs sql server 2008 express. But then I went and downloaded sql server 2008 R2 32 bit. Now I'm trying to find sql server management studio and I downloaded the stand-alone one from the ms site and when I launched it, it said that it doesn't support this version of sql server. Then I found a link that someone posted that points to a version of sql server management studio for sql server 2008 r2, but the 32 bit version doesn't have a download button. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985

Why is this so complicated? I just want to run sql server 2008 r2 and manage it with management studio.

Here is my installed packages:

[image]

And here is the services that are running (notice it says sqlexpress) But which one is it, the one that came with vs 2010 or the is it the one I downloaded and installed (i.e. sql server 2008 r2)?

[image]

Any suggestions on what I should do next? Where can I find sql server management studio that will work with my installs?

Comment: Which **package** did you install? The basic **Express** doesn't include Management Studio - you need the **Express with tools**

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985) for SQL Management Studio and scroll down to the "Instructions" section to find a link to [SQLManagementStudio_X86 Executable](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=186789&clcid=0x409)

Answer (score 1):

SQL server installation media should contain `Management Studio` on it. Look in `Shared features`.